# How can I use tag input in razor page

Tags: html, asp.net-core, input, razor-pages

I want to insert multiple numeric in tag input razor page like on picture below:

[image]

Want like car plate format and use in tag input. For example 12A123-22.

How can I use tag input in razor page? Maybe we can use validation for tel format?

Answer (score 2):

I believe using input masking is the best solution for this scenario. For example you can use this jQuery plugin: https://github.com/RobinHerbots/Inputmask

```
<input id="car-plate" data-inputmask="'mask': '99 A 999 - 99'" />

@section Scripts {
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $("#car-plate").inputmask();
        });
    </script>
}
```

Result:
[image: mask]

Codepen:
https://codepen.io/jimmys20/pen/oNdvNmq

Comment: tnx for your answer but "A" don't be fixed  client can change it for example B or C alphabet words

Comment: 'A' means 'any capital letter'. Same way, '9' means 'any number 0 to 9'. Check codepen from my answer and library documentation.